# Do we know if toasters exist?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004, cylon

In *Battlestar Galactica* (2004) - a common derogatory term for a cylon is a "toaster" (as in implying they are nothing more than simple common machines).
However, since the characters are in a futuristic civilisation that does things a little different to we do here on Earth, I have often wondered - should they even know what a toaster is? I know the obvious answer could be "Why wouldn't they?" but I'd still like to know:

Is there any evidence of a toaster, or a character eating toast in Battlestar Galactica?

Comment: I’m curious why having a word for toaster isn’t enough evidence for having toasters.

Comment: It could be that toasters are archaic technology, but the term has stuck around. Maybe people are saying "toaster" without knowing where the term originated

Comment: We say "upper case" despite the fact that approximately no one keeps their letters in cases anymore.

Comment: In cases like this I always assume that the language spoken in-universe is not mutually intelligible with present-day English (even if descended from it) and the dialog is a translation that captures the spirit of the word more than its literal meaning in the in-universe language.

Comment: Howdy doodly-do! Talkie's the name, toasting's the game. Would anybody like any toast? (maybe in BSG, Talkie Toaster - from Red Dwarf, which constantly badgers people into eating toast - is a thing. In that case, calling someone a toaster would be a perfectly derogatory term)

Comment: Given that God is infinite, and that the universe is also infinite, would you like a toasted teacake?

Comment: @Josh Ah, so you're a waffle man!

Comment: "My wife asked me why I carry a firearm while making breakfast.  I said 'Cylons.'  She laughed.  I laughed.  The toaster laughed.  I shot it.  Good times"

Comment: @Theodore "(even if descended from it)" Other way around, actually.

Comment: @Acccumulation I'm mostly unfamiliar with the BG universe except distant memories of the 1978 series (I was 9 then), which is why I only commented instead of answering.  To make my prior comment apply more broadly, replace the part in parentheses with: "(even if linguistically-speaking [genetecially related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_family) to it)".

Answer (score 84):

Season 1, Episode 5 you see Agathon make breakfast for Boomer, this includes a toaster seen about 1 minute in to this clip:

[image]

Comment: I am sure that somewhere (director's commentary maybe) it's stated that they deliberately chose a particularly chrome-y toaster for that scene to bring to mind a cylon.

Comment: For those not in the know - that is the famous [& very expensive] British-made Dualit Classic toaster, with a clumsy bit of card stuck over the rather large logo - https://www.dualit.com/products/2-slice-newgen

Comment: This may be a spoiler, but Helo is not making breakfast for Boomer. He’s making it for Athena who is impersonating Boomer.

Comment: @BenMurphy _May_ be? I don't know what the feeling is for spoilers on this site (and yours is not the only one I've seen even on this page), but that's definitely a spoiler. But perhaps I shouldn't be reading this page if I haven't seen it yet.

Comment: @bornfromanegg- It's not a spoiler, we know this isn't boomer as she's still aboard Galactica, and she can't be on Caprica and Galactica at the same time.

Comment: The toaster pictured and visible details of its construction and controls suggests that not only do food-preparation devices called “toasters” exist in BSG, but also “toast” as a verb and perhaps also a noun. Perhaps an additional source of rage for the metallic warrior Cylons kept mute by their meaty, human-shaped upper management is their electronically suppressed ability to retort to the humans, “And you are _toast_!”

Answer (score 27):

I want to tackle a different route than the given answer which found a toaster in the set. Not because that answer is incorrect (because it does solve the issue), but rather than I think your question derives from how you've defined your own words.

> should they even know what a toaster is?

You've sidetracked yourself into defining a "toaster" to very specifically use our real life technology, which is leading you to assume that a more futuristic version of the same device would not be a "toaster".

Bread exists. Bread can be toasted. The machine that toasts bread is called a toaster. This remains true regardless of the technological level of this machine. Whether it uses heated coils, kyber crystals, miniature dragons, nanotechnology, or opens a microportal to the sun.

Unless you are alleging that *toast* (whether bread or anything else that can be toasted) does not exist in the Battlestar Galactica universe, I see no reason to infer that toasters do not exist.

---

What's more important to understanding the insult is what a toaster represents relative to a Cylon.

The reason "toaster" is an insult is not because it's referring to a device with heated coils (i.e. how we build toasters in real life), it's because a toaster is a common everyday machine incapable of any other purpose other than what its designer intended for it to be capable of, which is significantly simpler than the capabilities of a living machine, which would be able to learn new things and through its learnings start to self-identify.

The word "toaster" debases the Cylons and devalues any shred of capability or identity that they have. This is no different from calling a human a meat sack or a knuckle dragger. This is the same principle as e.g. referring to women as cooks or maids or mothers, i.e. stating that they are limited to a small scope and either incapable of achieving other things or willfully ignoring any of their other achievements.

The reason "toaster" is used here is because of the dime-a-dozen nature of the device. If toasters were expensive state-of-the-art machines that are considered to be a impressive technological feat, it would not be an insult.

For example, if I were to refer to a Cylon as a Ferrari, that is *technically* still the same insult (because it's still a machine built for a single purpose), but it doesn't quite cut the same way because a Ferrari is an exceptionally well-made machine, hard to come by, and revered by many.

Comment: Yesss, but... it's also quite clear the insult "toaster" also refers to the appearance of the chromed Cylons as compared to the look of a classical/retro toaster (you can still get them chromed, too). It's not ANY expensive single-purpose device, it's specifically a device that looks like a chrome toaster. The heated coils themselves don't matter, but the specific look does.

Comment: @AndresF.: "Toaster" is a very common insult hurled at machines in real life and other fictional worlds; this is not unique to BSG by any stretch. [Example 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellaris/comments/16stnm8/how_to_insult_machine_empires/) [Example 2](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=toaster) I do agree that they likely picked a toaster in BSG (shown in the other answer) that resembled a Cylon. Whether that's an in-joke or a serious justification for the origins of the insult is arguable.

Comment: Yes, but this is *the future*. What if the entire galaxy's supply of bread had already been toasted by that time?

Comment: I understand why it's an insult, and also that even a futuristic toaster is still a toaster, but I don't but I don't recall seeing a character eating toast (at least I didn't prior to A.bakker's answer). While to us, the notion of having a single appliance for grilling bread seems obvious, we are talking about a civilisation from a completely different planet. e.g. I recently heard that many Americans don't have electric kettles (as inconceivable as that seems) so a Sci-Fi with Americans calling robots 'kettles' would be inappropriate. Is 'toaster' just for the audience's benefit?

Comment: @Flater I'm not going to press the issue, but the examples you mentioned aren't conclusive. For one, as a scifi trope, do you have an example that _clearly_ predates the re-imagined BSG? And the other use, a computer that is a "toaster", clearly makes reference to the heating capabilities of a toaster, so it's not ANY old clunky device used as a comparison, it's specifically a toaster! It also makes sense that they have roughly similar shapes (these are PCs of the era, a mainframe is never a toaster). Finally, the look in BSG cannot be discounted as an in-joke so easily.. Ockham Rzr applies :)

Comment: @Therac *Spoiler Alert* it’s actually in the very distant past.

Comment: @komodosp: In the US, electric kettles are sold at pretty much every shop that sells small kitchen appliances.  It's just that most Americans don't see the *need* for one, since a stove or microwave is *good enough* for the purpose of boiling water, so we don't feel the need to have a dedicated device.  We don't have the same tea-drinking culture as the British.  Coffee is the more popular hot beverage, and so many Americans do own coffeepots.

Comment: @komodosp: A "toaster" *could* be a translation convention for the audience.  Perhaps this society doesn't have Earth-style "bread" produced by grinding Pooideae-family grains into flour, mixing it with water, kneading the dough, and baking it.  But it's not too far-fetched that they'd have *some* staple food that is browned by a heat-induced Maillard reaction, a process which can reasonably be called "toasting".  Which makes the machine that produces it a "toaster".

Comment: Similar to how a "lamp" can operate by combustion (of a fuel like vegetable oil, kerosene, or natural gas), or with electricity (incandescent, fluorescent, or LED).  On an alien planet, it might refer to something completely different, like a glowing crystal.  The *purpose* of the thing is to produce light, and the exact mechanism of doing so is irrelevant.

Comment: @dan04 Also, US electric kettles are inferior to British ones.  This is because you can't draw as much power from a standard US outlet as from a standard British one.

Comment: I must disagree with the concept that the existence of toast implies the existence of toasters.  Star Trek--food made by replicators.  Yes, the pattern had to come from somewhere but that could have been long ago, toasters now being extinct.  And you can toast without a toaster.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: The BSG universe has never shown to have replicated food or similar scifi concepts w.r.t. how food is prepared. You can't just use something from one universe to disprove something in another, especially when they're this different.

Comment: @Flater I was just rebutting the notion that toast requires a toaster, not talking about the specific situation.

Comment: @AndresF.: Googling it for a while now, there seems to be consensus that the original BSG did _not_ use "toaster" and only using "tin can", which makes Star Trek TNG (1989) the earliest concrete example of "toaster" as a shorthand way of calling a robot an appliance. [1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151202/what-was-the-first-example-of-toaster-being-a-robot-slur) [2](https://www.trekbbs.com/threads/toaster-reference-star-trek-vs-bsg.125664/) However, like other posters as well, I'm certain I heard this used earlier, but it was likely in an off-hand way that is harder to trace.